# How to use reverse with split lines?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to parse the variable `output` and print the latest tag(by time) ,currently I am printing the oldest tag, is there a way to use `reverse` with split lines?

```
import re
output="""Fri Apr 27 18:43:20 2018 username3 <username3@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.1 to release1
Fri Apr 27 18:43:20 2018 username3 <username3@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.1 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E
Fri May 18 20:09:22 2018 username2 <username2@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.2 to release1
Fri May 18 20:09:22 2018 username2 <username2@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.2 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E
Fri Jun  8 13:35:44 2018 username1 <username1@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.3 to release1
Fri Jun  8 13:35:44 2018 username1 <username1@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.3 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E"""

train = "release2"
for line in output.splitlines():
    #print "line"
    #print line
    if re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line):
        print line
        break
```

OUTPUT:-

```
CoreCapture-274.1
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
CoreCapture-274.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use:

```
for line in reversed(output.splitlines()) :
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this `re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line):` ?

Comment: @user3508811 maybe you'd better ask a different question?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `splitlines` call in `reversed` and it will iterate the resulting lines in reverse order (without additional temporary `list`s):

```
for line in reversed(output.splitlines()):
```

Alternatively, if you need the `list` itself in reversed order, you can either two line it:

```
lines = output.splitlines()
lines.reverse()  # Reverses in place
```

or one-line it with a reversing slice (at the cost of an additional temporary `list`):

```
lines = output.splitlines()[::-1]  # Returns reversed list
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this `re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line):` ?

Comment: @user3508811: That's a completely separate question, and should really be asked on Code Review's StackExchange site. At a glance, if anything, you should be using `re.escape` on `train` to protect yourself if `train` ever contains regex special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
output="""Fri Apr 27 18:43:20 2018 username3 <username3@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.1 to release1
Fri Apr 27 18:43:20 2018 username3 <username3@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.1 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E
Fri May 18 20:09:22 2018 username2 <username2@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.2 to release1
Fri May 18 20:09:22 2018 username2 <username2@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.2 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E
Fri Jun  8 13:35:44 2018 username1 <username1@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-274.3 to release1
Fri Jun  8 13:35:44 2018 username1 <username1@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-274.3 to release2, release2E, release1E, release3, and release3E"""

train = "release2"
l=output.splitlines()
l.reverse()
for line in l:
    #print "line"
    #print line
    if re.match(r.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line):
        print line
        break
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this `re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line):` ?

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the regex is to use

```
if train in line:
    match = re.search(r'(submitted|forwarded)\s+(\S+)'
    if match:
        print match.group(2)
        break
```

Your version prints the whole line when you request the "word" after submitted|forwarded.

Comment: this won't work,Idea is not to get the word after submitted|forwarded,I want to match the line which has the corresponding train and then get the word

Comment: that is exactly what this does: 1) match the line which has the corresponding train `if train in line:` and 2) then get the word `if match:`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

m=re.fullmatch(r"(?ms).*(?:submitted|forwarded)\s+(.*?)\s+to(?!.*CoreCapture).*",output)
print(m.group(1))

Output:
CoreCapture-274.3
#------------------
(?ms)  m:multiline,s: . matches \n, too
(?!.*CoreCapture) negative lookahead to sure no more 'CoreCapture' string in the rest, so the group must match the last "CoreCapture".
```

But it doesn't handle the case "release2".
The enhanced version:

```
m=re.fullmatch(r"(?ms).*(?:submitted|forwarded)\s+(.*?)\s+to.*release2(?!.*CoreCapture.*release2).*",output)
```